# Infinite solution for linear nonhomogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to find $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following system $A\textbf{x}=\omega$ is true for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, with $\textbf{x}=(x,y)$. I let $A$ be the coefficient matrix and e $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^2$ a vector, then

$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2-2s & 2 r \\
2 r & 2s-2
\end{array}\right), \quad \omega=\left(\begin{array}{c}
s-1 \\
-r
\end{array}\right) .
$$

For the system to be true for **any** $x$ and $y$ I need it to be compatible and have $\infty^2$ solutions: hence I need the rank of the augmented matrix $(A|\omega)$ and the matrix $A$ to be both equal to 0.  Doing the computations I get $r=0$ and $s=1$. I am asking for a verification of my reasoning and my result. Thank you very much!